# Convert grib to netcdf file with wildflags in terminal for an complete folder

Tags: cdo-climate, eccodes

The syntax for using eccode to convert GRIB to NetCDF is clear. However, I'm wondering if there's a way to convert an entire folder of GRIB files into NetCDF using the old file names. I attempted to do this using the command below, but it didn't work:

```
grib_to_netcdf -o *.nc *.grib
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

---

Edit: If one prefers not to solve this through the Bash shell, the quickest solution is to use CDO conversion, even though the eccode module is more powerful and comprehensive.

Comment: You will need to use a loop and do the files one by one. The output in your file should only be a single file, not a wild card

Comment: Thanks a lot. I install now cdo :D that was faster and i can use it direct in a bash script without anly loops.